Retrieve Processed Form Data for Single Forms - Query Parameters
Using PostMan and the API docs listed here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-rest-api/op-api-rest-2.0-data-form-id-get.html
Do the endAt or startAt query parameters actually work?
When executing https://secure.p01.eloqua.com/api/rest/2.0/data/form/{formid}?startAt>1716247100 i would have expected it to return form submission data after Mon May 20 2024 23:18:20 GMT+0000 but it doesn't. Instead it returns the first 1000 records which is the default.
Using the count query parameter:
https://secure.p01.eloqua.com/api/rest/2.0/data/form/{formid}?count=150
It returns the first 150 form submissions so that works but endAt and startAt do not...has anyone gotten these to work?
thank you,
devin

unless you are encoding the >, there is no greater than query parameter operation
it should be https://secure.p01.eloqua.com/api/rest/2.0/data/form/{formid}?startAt=1716247100
